# Will Application.onCreate(Bundle) be called before BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(..)?

Tags: android

Just wanted to verify that `Application.onCreate()` is guaranteed to be called prior to `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` ?  Let say you are waiting for **BOOT** broadcast or **SMS** broadcast, can you be sure that `Application.onCreate()` has already been called once before you reach `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()`?  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)`
If you register a static receiver, the context is the app
otherwise it is the context where you call `registerReceiver` with

Comment: Well I just configuring the receiver in the manifest. So what's the conclusion about which guaranteed to get called first: MyApplication.onCreate(Bundle) or MyBroadcastReceiver.onReceive().

Comment: This is very reasonable, if you call `context.getApplicationContext()` inside the `onReceive`, what will it return?

Answer (score 22):

The docs tell us the following:

> public void onCreate ()
>
> Called when the application is starting, **before any** activity, service,
> or **receiver** objects (excluding content providers) have been created.

Found here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: Sadly, I assumed so but got proof it's not true of receivers, see my answer

Comment: In my experience, `BOOT_COMPLETED` receivers can be called before `Application.onCreate()`

Answer (score 5):

Old question, however I can provide an updated answer and actual test results.

Originally I assumed so and set my application onCreate() to save app context first, like so:

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    myapp.app_context = this;

    super.onCreate();
```

Now I got a receiver declared so:

```
    <receiver android:name=".myreceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And in on receive:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    ctx = myapp.app_context;
```

Got a stack trace showing ctx (myapp.app_context) is NULL! Got 1 on an Android 6 Galaxy J7 device and 1 on an Android 9 Xperia XZ1.

Comment: myapp is class name?

Comment: This is the application class, with a static Context app_context.